# Archived and sent email folders differ in Thunderbird, Spark and Outlook Web Access

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

I have a different behaviour whenever I send email or archive emails from my University in Thunderbird (pc), Spark (android app), or Outlook Web Access (where the emails are stored). The sent emails folder in thunderbird is different from the sent email folder in Outlook Web Access or Spark. Same for the Archive folder. For years I have been archiving in thunderbird, recently I have started using Spark or Outlook Web Access from my phone when on the go and I noticed they go to a different folder. What is the easiest procedure to make sure in all 3 cases they get archived in the same folder (analogously, sent email stored in the same folder).

Comment: These are different products, you can't expect them to be the same.

Comment: The archives do not even have the same extension. Outlook Mail is proprietary.

Comment: Agree with harrymc, it depends on the email app you used.